# Why should I assign the data type of variables in Kotlin if giving it values initially it is capable of inferring the data type of the variable

Tags: variables, kotlin

As mentioned in the code provided. My question is if there is any advantage by mentioning the data type early on when I am just giving the variable it's value. As said in line 2 it can understand that it is int type.

```
val a: Int = 1  // immediate assignment
val b = 2   // `Int` type is inferred
val c: Int  // Type required when no initializer is provided.
```

Comment: It can sometimes be more readable to specify the type (not with Int and Int literals, though). It can also be useful if you want the type to be something other than what is inferred (a super class or super interface, for example)

Comment: Is there any other advantage other than better readability of the code.

Comment: When doing interop with Java, the Kotlin compiler may not always be able to infer the nullability of objects coming from Java. So you may want to write `val foo : Foo? = getFooFromJava()` if you know that `getFooFromJava` can return a `null` reference (another alternative is to add annotations in the Java code, if modifying the Java code is an option).

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons you might want to specify a type explicitly:

- You want a supertype of the value (perhaps so you can to reassign it later), e.g.:

  `var myList: List<String> = ArrayList<String>()`
- You want to protect against changes to other code (especially if it's outside your control), e.g.:

  `val x: MustBeThisType = SomeLibrary.getValue()`

  (That would give an error if `SomeLibrary.getValue()` ever changes to returns something other than `MustBeThisType` or a subtype.)
- You want to avoid an explicit numeric conversion, e.g.:

  `val x: Long = 2`

  instead of:

  `val x = 2.toLong()`
- You want to make it very clear to someone reading your code (especially if that might not be in an IDE).
- As Michael says, you may need to specify the nullability of types returned from Java, e.g.:

  `val x: String = someJavaClass.getAString() // Never returns null`

None of those is particularly common in my experience, though.